# Estimate $ \int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))\right| dx$, where $f \in BV(\mathbb R)$ and $g$ is invertible

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f \in BV(\mathbb R)$ and $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an invertible function. How can we estimate
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} \left|\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))\right| dx$$
that is, the total variation of the composition? It is bounded by $TV(f) = \int_{\mathbb R} |\frac{d}{d y} f(y)| dy$ (maybe times a constant depending on the derivative of $g$ or of $g^{-1}$)?

Comment: Do you want an estimate on the total variation or the integral of the absolute value of the derivative? No, they're not always the same...

Answer (score 0):

First we should note that the total variation is not always the integral of the absolute value of the derivative: $f=\chi_{(0,\infty)}$.

I actually doubt that what you ask is true. But if we assume in addition that $g$ is continuous then it's trivial from the definitions that $TV(f\circ g)= TV(f)$.

Note that $g$ must be monotone; assume wlog that $g$ is increasing. Suppose $x_1\le x_2\le\dots\le x_n$. Then $$\sum|f\circ g(x_{j+1})-f\circ g(x_j)|=\sum|f(g(x_{j+1}))-f(g(x_j))|\le TV(f)$$by the definition of $TV(f)$, since $g(x_1)\le\dots\le g(x_n)$. Now taking the sup of the lhs shows $TV(f\circ g)\le TV(f)$.

Say  $h=f\circ g$. Then $g=h\circ g^{-1}$, so it follows that $TV(g)\le TV(h)$, since $g^{-1}$ is also a bijection.